# display arbitrary text in an Excel ComboBox on a Userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have 2 vertically touching ComboBoxes on an Excel Userform, both added at design time, and neither one having a bound column.  When a selection is made in ComboBox1, I'd like to show some text in ComboBox2, such as "Make further selection ===>".  This text should disappear when a selection is made in ComboBox2.

How can I do that?

Comment: In the Change Event for ComboBox1, use `ComboBox2.AddItem "Make further selection ===>"`. In the Change Event for ComboBox2, however, you'll need some logic that detects the selection, prevents "Make further selection" from being selected, and removes it using `ComboBox2.Remove "Make further selection ===>"`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use AddItem because I've set the ComboBox's RowSource equal to a Range, and trying to AddItem at runtime produces Runtime error 70 (permission denied).  I might try to use a ListBox instead of a Range for the RowSource list, to see if that will let me AddItem.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know what you want to achieve as a final result.

One possibility is a union query to set the row source of combo 2, say:

```
SELECT -1 As ID,"Make further selection ===>" As Something FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Something FROM Table1
```

You can use the After Update event of combobox1 to set the row source, but if you want the values to stick, you will need to set a bound column.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to force text into a ComboBox turns out to be really messy, out of all proportion to the minor effect I was trying to achieve.

So I've abandoned that approach and now instead of trying to put my text into the ComboBox, I'm putting it onto a Label positioned over top of ComboBox2 (but leaving the DropButton showing). Changing to a Label lets me format the text better, and I'm using the Change events of the two ComboBoxes to toggle the Z-order of the Label.

So the answer to my question is that trying to follow my original approach isn't worth the effort and that there are better ways to do it.